# Use beamer in article mode with hyperref

Tags: beamer, hyperref, beamerarticle

I want to create an article version of a `beamer` document.

The following MWE stops with error `! LaTeX Error: \beamer@descriptionitem undefined.`:

```
\documentclass[class=scrartcl]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerbasearticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I use `beamer.cls` 2013/01/04 3.26 and `hyperref.sty` 2012/11/06 v6.83m (actual TeX Live 2012).

If I remove `hyperref` everything works fine, but I need `hyperref` (my document contains `hyperref` commands like `\href`).

The sequence of loading the packages makes no difference, also `\documentclass[class=article, hyperref]{beamer}` does not work.

Any hints what I can do?

Edit:
In meantime I found a fix for me:
When I replace `hyperref` with `nohyperref` the document is created without error.
But it's not a real solution, with `nohyperref` I get no active links.

Comment: I think the method you are using is deprecated. To create an article version, I think you should use `\documentclass{scrartcl}` and `\usepackage{beamerarticle}` instead of `\documentclass[class=...]{beamer}` and `\usepackage{beamerbasearticle}`.

Comment: @cyberSingularity Thanks! This solved my problem. If you make an answer of it, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `beamer` `ChangeLog` dated `2004-09-23, Version 2.99`:

> Option `class=xxxx` [is] obsolete. Use document class `xxxx` directly
>         instead and load new style [package] `beamerarticle`.

Hence, you should use the following instead of the `class=` option and the `beamerbasearticle` package (note that the word `base` is not present in the replacement package name):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When using this approach, things should work as expected without conflicts etc.

**Further info**

There are no examples using the deprecated syntax in the `beamer` repository, except for some commented code in `beamerexample-prosper.tex` (at least I couldn't find anything else relevant when using `grep`).

The code in `beamer` which handles this option is in `beamerbasemodes.sty` (and it is quite a pain to trace some of the option handling in `beamer`...), and is preceeded by the following comment:

```
%
% Check whether we should initiate transfer to another class (obsolete)
%
```